# How to show sheet view after last item finished playing in AVQueuePlayer?

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer, avkit, avqueueplayer

I am playing an array of videos using `AVQueuePlayer`, but after the last video I see `AVQueuePlayer` trying to play the next video when there isn't any left. And what I'm trying to do is to toggle a boolean after the last item finished playing to show a sheet view. Can you guy please help me with this? Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply. Here is my code:

```
`struct Button : View {
            

@Binding var player : AVQueuePlayer
@Binding var isplaying : Bool
@State var showEnd = false
var removal: (() -> Void)? = nil
  
var body : some View {
    
    
     Button(action: {
       
     
            self.player.advanceToNextItem()
     }) {
         Image(systemName: self.isplaying ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
             .font(.title)
             .foregroundColor(.black)
             .padding(20)
     }
}
}


struct VideoPlayerS : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
@State var showEnd = false
var work : WorkoutDeS
@Binding var player : AVQueuePlayer
var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    
public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
    let items = [
        
        AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: String(work.url1))),
        AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: String(work.url2)))
        
    ]
   let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
       let controller = AVPlayerViewController()

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.player = player
       }
    controller.player = player
    controller.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

  

    
    
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
        self.player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        self.player.play()
    }
    player.play()
    

  
    
    return controller
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an observer on the queue player's `currentItem`. When the observer method is called and there are no items in the player, it has played its last item.